# Regexp for finding out space and '/' character in user input using actionscript 3

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex

UserID should not have space as well as '/' (forward slash) characters.

I'm trying out a regexp in actionscript (as3) to test the user input.

I tried out something like this.. `/[^\s\/]/`

I'm new to actionscript3.

Could someone please give your valuable suggestions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add start and end anchors and also you have to add `+` after the negated character class `[^\s\/]`. So that it would match any character but not of space or forward slash one or more times.

```
> /^[^\s\/]+$/.test("foo g")
false
> /^[^\s\/]+$/.test("foog")
true
> /^[^\s\/]+$/.test("foo/g")
false
```

Answer (score 1):

If user input comes straight from a `TextField`, you may find it easier to use the properties `restrict` and `maxChars` of `TextField` class that provide built-in control of the number of chars and charset allowed in a text input.

If you need more complicated rules, you will need regexp, but in your case it should be enough:

```
my_txt.restrict = "^ /";
```

Documentation for [TextField.restrict](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#restrict) and [TextField.maxChars](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#maxChars)